# MYSQL : SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mariadb

I keep getting this error when i try to bacth insert into my sql database even though the time format is correct:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (22007)
>       SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-10 02:00:01' for column 'created_at' at row 850

Unless i'm wrong, '2019-03-10 02:00:01' is a valid date format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203899/sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value-2008-0

Comment: Check the timezone, and when Daylight Savings comes or goes.  Then think about `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.