# MySql datetime: throwing error for date in DateTime::DATE_ATOM

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I got MySql 5.7 DB on hosting.
DB contains table with datetime column. for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_date (
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
)
```

There is some date in PHP application which we should store into datetime column. To achieve that date is formatted using DateTime::DATE_ATOM format.
PHP application is inserting record into that table using some framework (this is not important) so finally INSERT query is looking as the following:

```
INSERT INTO `test_date`(`date`) VALUES ('2018-05-22T12:33:16-03:00')
```

but MySql is throwing an error:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2018-05-22T12:33:16-03:00' for column 'date' at row 1
```

if I remove time zone offset from string (**-03:00**) insert is completed successfully.

I have multiple instances of MySql 5.6 installed on local VM and on different remote data centers but I never faced this issue: MySql always worked correctly with datetime formatted using DateTime::DATE_ATOM.

I digged Google but didn't find any specific changes in MySql 5.7 related to  datetime.

Can you please point me why DateTime::DATE_ATOM string is rejected by MySql 5.7 or provide any pointers?

**Update:** looks like root cause of this issue is missed NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION sqlMode (ref [MYSQL incorrect DATETIME format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598629/mysql-incorrect-datetime-format)). Looks like it is set by default on most of installations (or admins are setting it) but not on my hosting.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html describes the syntax of `DATETIME` literals. I don't see anything about allowing a timezone offset. I suspect 5.6 was just ignoring this, and 5.7 has gotten more strict, or maybe you have different SQL modes set.